# How to change the document background color when select list option for that color is selected

Tags: javascript, select, background-color

```js
function change_color() {
  var getSelect = document.getElementsByName("colorPick");
  var selection = getSelect.options[getSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  for (i = 0; i < getSelect.options.length; i++) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = selection;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="colorPick" onchange="change_color();">
  <option value="0">Background Color</option>
  <option value="1">Blue</option>
  <option value="2">Cyan</option>
  <option value="3">White</option>
</select>
```

/*Something is wrong.  I have tried many different things but nothing seems to work when I select a color.*/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code wasn't working because [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns a nodeList collection of element. You needed to access one of the elements, as you can't get the value of the collection.

```
document.getElementsByName("colorPick")[0]; // First element
```

---

You could avoid this by passing the context of the select element: `onchange="change_color(this)"`.

In terms of changing the background color, you need to set the `body` element's background color to the *text* of the selected element. Not the value.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozsxj2th/)

```js
function change_color(select) {
    var color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent;
    
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<select name="colorPick" onchange="change_color(this);">
    <option value="0">Background Color</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Cyan</option>
    <option value="3">White</option>
</select>
```

---

I'd suggest using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) though:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gg60c5k2/)

```js
document.querySelector('[name="colorPick"]').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var color = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
    
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
});
```

```html
<select name="colorPick">
    <option value="0">Background Color</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Cyan</option>
    <option value="3">White</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
<body>
<select name="colorPick" onchange="change_color();">
<option value="0">Background Color</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Cyan">Cyan</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
</select>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
function change_color() {
    var getSelect = document.getElementsByName("colorPick");
    var selection = getSelect[0].options[getSelect[0].selectedIndex].value;
    for (i = 0; i < getSelect[0].options.length; i++) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = selection;
    }
}
```